# How can I create a custom typography with for and loop on php?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a program that gives an oputput like:
(Look's like "X" inside the box)

```
********
**xxx*x*
*x*xx*x*
*xx**xx*
*xx**xx*
*x*xx*x*
**xxxx**
********
```

But always stack on this shape:

```
********
*xxxxxx*
*xxxxxx*
*xxxxxx*
*xxxxxx*
*xxxxxx*
*xxxxxx*
********
```

with this code:

```
for($out=0; $out<8; $out++) {
    for($in=0; $in<8; $in++) {
        if($out==0 || $out==8-1) {
            echo "*";
        } else {
            if($in==0 || $in==8-1) {
                echo "*";
            } else {
                echo "x";
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Can you give me advise to this case?

Comment: advise about what ? ..

Comment: how to make a logic or code to make the shape that I want :) @DTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if im helping you with homework right now :)

Here is ONE solution among others:

```
for($out=0; $out<8; $out++) 
{
    for($in=0; $in<8; $in++) 
    {
        if($out==0 || $out==8-1) 
        {
            echo "*";
        } 
        else if($in == 0 || $in ==8-1)
        {
            echo "*";
        }
        else 
        {
            if($in == $out) 
            {
                echo "*";
            } 
            else if($out+$in == 7)
            {
                echo "*";
            }
            else 
            {               
                echo "x";
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<br/>";
}
```

The "trick" is to find a pattern and translate that to code .. The pattern i used is simple. The line going from top left to bottom right can be drawn if x and y postion are equal. The line from top right to bottom left can be drawn if x + y positions equal 7 .. Thats the pattern i used for drawing X...

Comment: Thank DTH. that's cool. but I still need left and right show "*" :)

Comment: @DavidRivaldy i handle the edges in the two first if / else if clauses. The last else is there to handle the drawing in-between... hope it works for you :)

Comment: @DavidRivaldy Please dont be like that to seek help, and not even honor the answer .. its what creates a bad spirit among those who try to help people who post problems. It will result in people like me not wanting to help people like you with answers to your "problems" when we see people with 1 point of reputation .. Where would you go to seek help then ?